# Why does the transfer function need to have an amount parameter?

Tags: tokens

The following function must be implemented for a token to be ERC-20 compliant:

```
    // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account
15     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
16         if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount 
17             && _amount > 0
18             && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
19             balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
20             balances[_to] += _amount;
21             return true;
22         } else {
23             return false;
24         }
25     }
```

Notice that one of the parameters is the `_amount`.  That's the amount that the user specifies. However, isn't one of the internal properties of a transaction the `msg.value` parameter? That means that the `_amount` variable is redundant, and a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, *_amount* is not redundant; the variable *msg.value* denotes the number of **wei** (not token, but ether itself) sent along with the transaction! See also [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html).